# How would I maintain a large amount of code used in two different programs (using git)?

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I have a lot of Javascript code that will be deployed inside a desktop application and used as a web application (deployed to a server).

The only method that is obvious to me is to have the desktop application pull the source code when it builds.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at git submodules.  You would treat the JS as a shared library and thus include it as a submodule in both the Web and Desktop applications.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: As an alternative, you might also research [subtree merge](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html).